# JavaScript Regular Expression last match

Tags: javascript, regex

To search in the string `a='c761uc762uc201tc202t'` and get the closest number before `1t`.

Expect to get `20`, but with `a.match(/(c*){2,}(.*?)1t/)`, I get `["c761uc762uc201t", "", "761uc762uc20"]`.

`a` may be like `c*1uc*2uc*1tc*2t` or `c*1uc*1t`. If `a` is `"c761uc201t"`, also expect to get `"20"` in this case.

Any hint how should I write the regular expression to get `20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var r = a.match(/^(?:[^c]*c){1,3}(.*)1t/)[1];
// 20
```

Or to make it safer:

```
var r = (a.match(/^(?:[^c]*c){1,3}(.*)1t/) || [null, null])[1];
// 20

a='c*1uc*2uc*1tc*2t';
var r = (a.match(/^(?:[^c]*c){1,3}(.*)1t/) || [null, null])[1];
// *

a='c*1uc*1t'
r = (a.match(/^(?:[^c]*c){1,3}(.*)1t/) || [null, null])[1]
// null

a="c761uc201t";
r = (a.match(/^(?:[^c]*c){1,3}(.*)1t/) || [null, null])[1]
// 20
```

Comment: @Ovilia But there isn't a 3 c's in the above string.

Comment: @Ovilia: How can we get `20` from `c761uc201t` when there are only 2 `c`'s

Answer (score 2):

This is my go on this question:

```
/(\d{2})\dt$/
```

This will fetch the number before any `<number>t` at the end of the string.

```js
>>> 'c761uc762uc201tc202t'.match(/(\d{2})\dt$/);
Array ["202t", "20"]
>>> 'c761uc201t'.match(/(\d{2})\dt$/);
Array ["201t", "20"]
```

This was the shortest answer I could come up with.

If you want only the one after `1t`, try this:

```
/(\d{2})1t/
```

This works like this:

```js
>>> 'c761uc762uc201tc202t'.match(/(\d{2})1t/);
Array ["201t", "20"]
>>> 'c761uc201t'.match(/(\d{2})1t/);
Array ["201t", "20"]
```